# Googleマップの情報を取得してGoogleスプレットシートに反映させたい

Tags: google-spreadsheet

スプレットシートのA3「店舗名」を入れました。
その店舗名でヒットしたgoogleマップの情報をスプレットシートへ反映させたいのです。
反映させたい情報はB3に★の数、C3に口コミ数、D3に総合評価の点数を反映させたいです。
そんな事はできるのでしょうか？
ちなみにA4，A5に続けて店舗名が連なっているので同様に反映させていきたいです。
プロの皆様、経験のある方教えてください。。。